# GTM datalayer not pushing to Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I am trying to set up ecommerce tracking within Google Analytics using a datalayer to push the data however I am not receiving any data in Google Analytics?

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
<script>
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []
dataLayer.push({
'transactionId': '1238393768',
'transactionAffiliation': 'Website Name',
'transactionTotal': 105.78,
'transactionTax': 21.156,
'transactionShipping': 18.00,
'transactionProducts': [
                {
                'sku': '97',
                'name': 'Product',
                                    'category': 'Category One, Category Two',                
                                    'price': 3.99,
                'quantity': 22            }

]
});
</script>

<!-- Google Tag Manager Tracking Code Located After Datalayer -->
```

Comment: Got solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You gotta set the `event` for it to fire. This can be either `checkout` or `transaction`. You also need to set the `ecommerce` event as either `checkout` or `transaction`. `transactionId` goes into `actionField` and you can also add the checkout step or the currency type in here.

Here's the correct way to do it:

```
window.dataLayer.push({
'event' : 'checkout',
'ecommerce' : {
    'checkout' : {
        "actionField" : {
                    'transactionId': '1238393768'},                                                 'transactionAffiliation': 'Website Name',
                    'tansactionTotal': 105.78,
                    'transactionTax': 21.156,
                    'transactionShipping': 18.00,
                    'transactionProducts': [{
                        'sku': '97',
                        'name': 'Product',
                        'category': 'Category One, Category Two',                
                        'price': 3.99,
                        'quantity': 22
                        }]
                    }
}});
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am still struggling to get analytics to pick up this data :( Just to confirm I need to update where it says ecommerce in your code to be either checkout or transaction? Also does the location of the code matter? I've added my datalayer to the top of my <head> tag?

Comment: The above link doesn't mentioned that I need an event for this to fire? I am using the code provided in the example?

Answer (score 0):

Did you setup the GA Transaction tag in the GTM interface? Simply populating the dataLayer object isn't enough. You also need to setup the Trigger in the tag so that the tag is fired on your order confirmation page where your dataLayer object is set.

[Add the Transaction tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLW2i.jpg)

More info can be found here: https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6107169?hl=en#standard-ecommerce

If you have the Tag and Trigger setup correctly in GTM, then another possible reason data is not showing in GA is that you may not have Ecommerce tracking enabled in the GA interface, here are instructions from Google's site since SO not letting me post 2 links in same answer:

===================================

**Enable Ecommerce for a view**

You need to enable Ecommerce for each view in which you want to see the data.

1. Sign in to Google Analytics.
2. Click Admin, and navigate to the view
   you want.
3. In the VIEW column, click Ecommerce Settings.
4. Set Enable Ecommerce to ON.
5. Optional: Set Enable Related Products to ON.
6. Click Next step.
7. Click Submit.

===================================

Comment: Based on the OP's sample code he's clearly not using Enhanced Ecommerce so the answers from Marco and I.R.R. are not valid. The OP's sample code is using Standard Ecommerce.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#purchases) to properly send EE data.

```
<script>
dataLayer.push({
  'ecommerce': {
    'purchase': {
      'actionField': {
        'id': 'T12345',                         
        'affiliation': 'Online Store',
        'revenue': '35.43',                     
        'tax':'4.90',
        'shipping': '5.99',
        'coupon': 'SUMMER_SALE'
      },
      'products': [{                            
        'name': 'Triblend Android T-Shirt',     
        'id': '12345',
        'price': '15.25',
        'brand': 'Google',
        'category': 'Apparel',
        'variant': 'Gray',
        'quantity': 1,
        'coupon': ''                            
       }]
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Plus you should have in mind in the tag configuration you need to activate the use of dataLayer for eCommerce data.

[image: eCommerce Tag]

Finally, [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce?hl=es-419#ecommerce-data) are the references for every param you can send in EE and if they are optional or not.